# Sequel::AdapterNotFound: LoadError: cannot load such file -- java

Tags: java, ruby

I have installed jruby-1.7.16 using rvm and having java open jdk version 1.7.0_75.

bundle install gets success 
below are the errors when I run the bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace

```
test@pts00433-vm8:~/Travis/travis-logs$ bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace

Jdbc-Postgres is only for use with JRuby
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
Sequel::AdapterNotFound: LoadError: cannot load such file -- java
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/adapters/jdbc.rb:1:in `require'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/adapters/jdbc.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:29:in `require'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:29:in `adapter_class'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:52:in `connect'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:95:in `connect'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/lib/travis/logs/helpers/database.rb:18:in `create_sequel'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/Rakefile:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- java
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/adapters/jdbc.rb:1:in `require'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/adapters/jdbc.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:29:in `require'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:29:in `adapter_class'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/database/connecting.rb:52:in `connect'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sequel-4.0.0/lib/sequel/core.rb:95:in `connect'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/lib/travis/logs/helpers/database.rb:18:in `create_sequel'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/Rakefile:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/test/Travis/travis-logs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Comment: is there more to this trace message?

Comment: Hi meatsapce I have update errors with command run bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace